# axios 1.6.2 transpiled to .cjs

Tags: reactjs, axios, cjs

I have a react component that uses axios 1.6.2
And it has these line:

```
import axios from "axios";

export const makeAxiosCall = () => {
    let axiosInstance = axios.create(......);
    //Make axios call
}
```

When I test this using yarn storybook, axios works fine and makes an API call.

In my package.json scripts section, I have this line:
"transpile": "./node_modules/.bin/babel src -d dist --copy-files --ignore src/**/*.stories.js ",

Once I do:
yarn transpile

And use this component in my Main component, I got an error when it tries to make an API call:

Error:
_axios.default.create is not a function

And when I observe the value of _axios in the browser console, I saw this:

> _axios
> {
> default: '/static/media/axios.7a2137e03d7017b9607.cjs'
> }

That is why I got the above error.
I didn't see this error in axios 0.26.0 but 1.6.2
Any suggestions to fix this?

Comment: Change your import statement to use the named import syntax instead. This will import the ```axios``` directly from the axios module, because, it seems that the default export is not the ```axios``` function you're expecting, but rather a string that represents the path to the axios module.